# Angular Injectable Toastr Service is undefined

Tags: angular, angular8, toastr

I created a custom Toastr service (more of a wrapper class if you will). I inject this in my data service (api calls) but every time I call it I get an error that its undefined. If I use this service in a component then it works fine.

I think it might have to do how I use it in my Put call.

How I export my ToastrWrapperClass

```
@Injectable()
export class ToastrAlertService {
```

I inject it here and it references my correct service

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
        private apiEndpointService: ApiEndpointsService,
        private adapter: UserAdapter,
        private toastrAlertService: ToastrAlertService,
    ) { }
```

Here I call my Handle Error (I think it might be by how I am handling the 'catchError' here

```
public put(model: User): Observable<User> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    const putModel = {
        Model: model,
    };

    return this.http.put(this.apiEndpointService.apiUrl(this.apiType + '/'), JSON.stringify(putModel), { headers }).pipe(
        map((data: any) => this.adapter.adapt(data)), catchError(this.handleError),
    );
}
```

This toastrAlertService is 'undefined' when the error gets returned from my API

```
handleError(error) {
    this.toastrAlertService.showErrorToast(error);
    return throwError(error);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handling the catchError as follows solved it for me. (I did move the handle error logic to a single class to make the code cleaner)

```
 return this.http.put(this.apiEndpointService.apiUrl(this.apiType + '/'), JSON.stringify(model), { headers }).pipe(
        map((data: any) => this.adapter.adapt(data)),
        catchError(err => {
            this.apiErrorHandlerService.handleError(err);
            return of(null);
        }),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you providing the ToastrService?

**Beginning with Angular 6.0** the preferred to create a singleton service is to set `providedIn` to `root` on the service's `@Injectable()` decorator. This tells Angular to provide the service in the application root. ([see angular docs for more info](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services))

Here are some examples of how to provide the service either in:

**The AppModule:**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ToastrAlertService {
```

or

**Withing a lazy loaded Module:**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: LazyLoadedModuleName
})
export class ToastrAlertService {
```

Comment: Both services live in my Core Module (ToastrAlertService and UserService). Other components outside of the core module calls it fine.